# Django "ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes"

Tags: django, django-models

I am facing this error:

```
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

whenever I create a `splite3` database and use it.

Below are the steps i follow:

1. Create the database using db browser.
2. Run `python manage.py inspectdb > customer.py`
3. Run the server with `python manage.py runserver`

I get this error when I run the server. Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Please provide the *full* traceback.

Comment: Does the server run without the file `customer.py`, meaning, does the error only happen when this file is present?

Comment: i don't now why but when I remove the app declaration on Installed app in setting.py the error disappear.

Comment: To answer your question yes the error happen only when customer.py is generated (automatically) they might be some correction to perform on the models before migration

Comment: I meet this issue again. After generating models by cmd "python manage.py inspectdb > customer.py", I have this error. I still can't fix. Hope someone have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

open the file in IDLE or notepad and save it again with UTF-16 Encoding

Answer (score 0):

This could be an encoding error. You can try this:

1. Copy the code generated by inspectdb (Ex: models.py)
2. Open a text editor or notepad (select UTF-8)
3. Save the file
4. Replace the old file with this new one